# XmlService unable to parse records due to text in XLMNS attribute (Google AppScript)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, xml-parsing

XmlService is unable to parse records when "xmlns" attribute is populated with any text, i.e.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
```

However when I remove this text then the XmlService is able to parse the records:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="">
```

I'm using the following code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  let fileID = '1a2WKxQEzrNZKUAolqE23nykvfgYos7xD';
  let url = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID).getBlob().getDataAsString();  
  let document = XmlService.parse(url);

  let root = document.getRootElement();

  let entries = root.getChildren("entry");
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    let id = entry.getChild('id').getText();
    Logger.log(id);
  });

  Logger.log('prayer hands');
}
```

And here's the contents of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed version="0.3" xmlns="http://purl.org/atom/ns#">
    <title>tes-6.5/tes:Node.getIds</title>
    <category term="0" scheme="row" label=""/>
    <category term="0" scheme="level" label=""/>
    <category term="111111111111111111111111" scheme="securitypolicy" label=""/>
    <category term="000000000000000000000000" scheme="customsecuritypolicy" label=""/>
    <category term="33" scheme="count" label=""/><category term="N" scheme="changedOnly" label=""/><category term="" scheme="groupNameRecordPosition" label=""/>
    <category term="0" scheme="jobOrJobRunRecordPosition" label=""/>
    <generator uri="http://www.software.com">TES</generator>
    <modified>2022-08-30T15:23:24.077-06:00</modified>
    <entry>
        <id>-2</id>
        <title>Fault Monitor</title><category term="0" scheme="row" label=""/>
        <category term="0" scheme="level" label=""/>
        <category term="111111111111111111111111" scheme="securitypolicy" label=""/>
        <category term="000000000000000000000000" scheme="customsecuritypolicy" label=""/>
        <category term="33" scheme="count" label=""/>
        <category term="N" scheme="changedOnly" label=""/>
        <category term="" scheme="groupNameRecordPosition" label=""/>
        <category term="0" scheme="jobOrJobRunRecordPosition" label=""/>
        <source>com.software.etc</source>
        <tes:node xmlns:tes="http://www.software.com/client/tesservlet">
            <tes:id>-2</tes:id>
        </tes:node>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>-1</id>
        <title>Fault Monitor</title><category term="0" scheme="row" label=""/>
        <category term="0" scheme="level" label=""/>
        <category term="111111111111111111111111" scheme="securitypolicy" label=""/>
        <category term="000000000000000000000000" scheme="customsecuritypolicy" label=""/>
        <category term="33" scheme="count" label=""/>
        <category term="N" scheme="changedOnly" label=""/>
        <category term="" scheme="groupNameRecordPosition" label=""/>
        <category term="0" scheme="jobOrJobRunRecordPosition" label=""/>
        <source>com.software.etc</source>
        <tes:node xmlns:tes="http://www.software.com/client/tesservlet">
            <tes:id>-2</tes:id>
        </tes:node>
        </entry>
</feed>
```

Please where am I going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your following issue,

> XmlService is unable to parse records when "xmlns" attribute is populated with any text, i.e.:

> However when I remove this text then the XmlService is able to parse the records:

When I saw your showing XML data and script, I thought that in your script, in order to retrieve the values, it is required to use the name space. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
let entries = root.getChildren("entry");
entries.forEach(entry => {
  let id = entry.getChild('id').getText();
  Logger.log(id);
});
```

#### To:

```
let ns = root.getNamespace();
let entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
entries.forEach(entry => {
  let id = entry.getChild('id', ns).getText();
  Logger.log(id);
});
```

- By this modification, when your `url` is the your showing XML data, `-2`, `-1`, and `prayer hands` are shown in the log.

#### Reference:

- [getNamespace()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getnamespace)

Comment: Confirmed updated code is sufficient to my situation. Thank you!

Comment: @Marc Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.